# Insserv and LSBbase: fixing Aptitude in Debian? Cannot install anything, why?

Tags: installation, debian, aptitude

Error reports [here](http://pastie.org/4796007) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187142/aptitude-not-working-after-sources-list-messup). Instructions [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=55972) suggests insserv but I am unable to install anything so cannot get insserv running. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problems at least with [LSBbase](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts), insserve, LSBheaders. I thank #Debian and Trxmxr for helping me out, I got it working!

> **1. Puzzle**
>
> > Fix the headers of `/etc/init.d/couchdb` to `"+mountall +mountoverflowtmp +umountfs"` in the position of local_fs.
>
> **2. Puzzle (errs example [here](http://pastie.org/4811703))**
>
> > Fix LSB -headers problem by copying the headers of Cups for example to Smfpd -samsung-printer-thing`/etc/init.d/smfpd`, remember to modify
> >     a bit. Further info [here](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts).
>
> **3. Puzzle**
>
> > Fix the bug with `rc-status` -thing by this command `"sudo touch /etc/rc.status"`.
>
> **4. Puzzle**
>
> > By comparing to working system, Trxmor realized that lsb-base had to be reinstalled, wrong settings [here](http://pastie.org/4811891). So
> >     `"$ sudo aptitude reinstall lsb-base"`.

**Commands to diagnose**

**1. insserv**

> According to Trxmxr, no decision yet made to switch away from insserve to something else.
>
> **Definitions**
>
> - `'$ is a "virtual" target, i.e. not a
>     real startup script but an alias or group of multiple targets'`
> - `'+ is an optional member of a group'`. The mistake has something to
>     do with the Required-Start -thing.
>
> **Some Commands**
>
> - $ grep "_fs" /etc/init.d/couchdb
> - $ head /etc/insserv.conf

**2. updating and upgrading**

> If you get mistakes firing, rollback to the puzzles -- example below how I configured things.
>
> ```
> $ wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/insserv/insserv_1.14.0-4_i386.deb
> $ sudo dpkg -i --force-confdef insserv_1.14.0-4_i386.deb
> $ sudo dpkg --configure -a
> $ sudo apt-get upgrade
> ```